# Add link gone from main menu and getting errors when trying to add new menu item

Tags: views, navigation, taxonomy-terms

Running D7

For some reason the add link is gone from the admin menu view...can only edit but can't add any links or menu items, getting errors also:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'hierarchical_select' in 
drupal_array_set_nested_value() (line 6776 of 
C:\aquiasites\redoII\includes\common.inc).

Fatal error: Cannot create references to/from string offsets nor 
overloaded objects in C:\aquiasites\redoII\includes\common.inc on line 
6776
```

I disabled hierarchical_select to no avail...I can't find the view to control those settings, but this is a core view right?

Usually menus say:

```
    list links    edit menu    add link
```

But now these options are gone...

It only says:

```
    MENU LINK   ENABLED TARGET  OPERATIONS
```

[image: Add link gone from menu]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the answer, eventually another error popped up when trying usermenu:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset '#value' in 
content_menu_form_menu_item_delete_form_alter() (line 270 of 
C:\aquiasites\redoII\sites\all\modules\content_menu
\content_menu.module)
```

I disabled all possible menu plugins...the offending module didn't create any errors on main menu and other, **ONLY on usermenu...**

Disabled this module https://www.drupal.org/project/content_menu

Now works fine